# How to loop an HTML video from a specific point

Tags: html, loops, video, controls

I have a video.

http://www.redrose.com.br/riosultec/

I know the `loop` attribute loops from the start, but I would like to loop it after the third second. This is after the logo enters the screen.

I tried many things but I didn't find any solution for this.

I saw another topic about using `JavaScript` to load the video in a specific point.

I tried to convert it to reload the video and start only at the point I wanted but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

This probably can only be done in JavaScript.

Videos have a `duration` attribute that returns the length of a video. We can also get the `currentTime` of a video, check if it equals the midpoint, and reset it to 0.

```
var video = document.getElementById("my-video");

var midway = (video.duration / 2);

setInterval(function() {
    if (video.currentTime === midway) {
        video.currentTime = 0;
   }
},0);
```

Comment: i realy dont know how to to that i used your script but it dont work :(

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question but I just needed to do something similar. You can achieve this using ontimeupdate and including a 'loop' attribute for the html video tag. When the video reaches the end it should jump back to 3 seconds.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <video id="video" autoplay controls muted loop width="560" height="315" src="video.mp4">
    </video>
    <script>
    var video = document.getElementById('video');

    video.ontimeupdate = function(){
        //3 below represent the 3 seconds from the original question, but could be set to anything
        if (video.currentTime == video.duration || video.currentTime < 3){
            video.currentTime = 3
        }
    }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```